# Is there any quick way to get comment count of all open pull request

Tags: github-api

I have a requirement to find count of comments in all open pull request of a repository

Only way i know is to get all open pull request from a repo and iterate each pull request and perform call like this

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:pull_number/comments
```

and sum up those responses, But it is too costly

I also tried with this method ( Find review comments on all PR in a repo)

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/comments
```

and passed state = open as query param like this

```
https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/pulls/comments?per_page=30&state=open
```

But it returns review comments of all pull requests

Any efforts will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Github API Rest v3](https://developer.github.com/v3/), you can use a search query like this :

https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=is:pr%20state:open%20repo:angular/angular&per_page=100

You can use [GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/) using the following query :

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "angular", name: "angular") {
    pullRequests(states: OPEN, first: 100) {
      nodes {
        title
        comments {
          totalCount
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20repository(owner%3A%20%22angular%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22angular%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pullRequests(states%3A%20OPEN%2C%20first%3A%20100)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20comments%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A)

Or using a search query like this :

```graphql
{
  search(type: ISSUE, query: "is:pr state:open repo:angular/angular", first: 100) {
    nodes {
      ... on PullRequest {
        title
        comments {
          totalCount
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20search(type%3A%20ISSUE%2C%20query%3A%20%22is%3Apr%20state%3Aopen%20repo%3Aangular%2Fangular%22%2C%20first%3A%20100)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20PullRequest%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20comments%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)

If you want reviews count & reviews comment as well you could use :

```graphql
{
  search(type: ISSUE, query: "is:pr state:open repo:angular/angular", first: 100) {
    nodes {
      ... on PullRequest {
        title
        comments {
          totalCount
        }
        reviews(first: 100) {
          totalCount
          nodes {
            comments {
              totalCount
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20search(type%3A%20ISSUE%2C%20query%3A%20%22is%3Apr%20state%3Aopen%20repo%3Aangular%2Fangular%22%2C%20first%3A%20100)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20PullRequest%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20comments%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reviews(first%3A%20100)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20comments%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Using [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) :

```bash
repo_owner=angular
repo_name=angular
token=YOUR_TOKEN

curl -s -H "Authorization: bearer $token" -d '
{
    "query": "query {repository(owner: \"'$repo_owner'\", name: \"'$repo_name'\") {pullRequests(states: OPEN, first: 100) {nodes {title comments {totalCount}}}}}"
}
' https://api.github.com/graphql
```