# How do I access all comments in a "conversation" via Github GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, github-api

A Github Pull Request shows a count of items in a "conversation".
[Pull request tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE1Gv.png)

How do I access all the elements which make this total up via the GraphQL API?

I've tried retrieving the `comments` against the Pull Request, as well as the `comments` against the `reviews` for the Pull Request as indicated in this question:

[Is there any quick way to get comment count of all open pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58678266/is-there-any-quick-way-to-get-comment-count-of-all-open-pull-request)

```
{
  search(type: ISSUE, query: "is:pr state:open repo:foo/bar", first: 100) {
    nodes {
      ... on PullRequest {
        title
        comments {
          totalCount
        }
        reviews(first: 100) {
          totalCount
          nodes {
            comments {
              totalCount
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However I can't seem to access when a user has "responded" to a comment.  In the case of the example PR I'm looking at, by extracting the `reviews` collection I can see 16 items, however the "Conversation" tab shows 21 items - so there are 5 `comments` that have a "Reply".  What do I need to do to my query to return those?  It's just the count that I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a reason I can't figure out how to retrieve them - you can't.

https://github.community/t/bug-v4-graphql-api-not-possible-to-fetch-replies-to-a-review-comment-in-timeline-items-for-a-pull-request/222106

> It is still not possible to fetch the replies of a review comment consistently from the `timelineItems`.